# Migrating from Eclipse to Android-Studio (gradle)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to migrate my applications to use gradle, but I'm facing some problems including library projects.

My project tree is this:

```
My projects root
- MyLib1
-- res
-- src
-- libs
- MyLib2
-- res
-- src
-- libs
- MyLib3
-- res
-- src
-- libs
- MyAppBase
-- res
-- src
-- libs
- MyApp - full version
-- res
-- src
-- libs
- MyAppFree - free version
-- res
-- src
-- libs
```

With Eclipse I had the following dependencies

```
MyAppBase depends on:
-MyLib1
-MyLib2
-MyLib3

MyApp depends on:
-MyAppBase
-MyLib1
-MyLib2
-MyLib3

MyAppFree depends on:
-MyAppBase
-MyLib1
-MyLib2
-MyLib3
```

This organization worked well within Eclipse, but now with Android-Studio and gradle I'm having problems.

I've got the following build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    //compile project('../MyLib1')  <- error
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

How can I include the projects MyLib1, MyLib2, MyLib3 as a dependency so It will be compiled along with my project???

Answer (score 1):

At present, all dependencies need to live under the project's root directory, so you'd need to set up your project to be rooted at the directory above **MyLib1**, **MyLib2**, **MyApp**, etc. This limitation will be lifted in the future; you can track its progress at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56367. Your libraries would be library modules under that root, and your app(s) would be Android application modules. Each module has its own separate `build.gradle` file and can compile to a JAR (plain Java library), AAR (Android library, which includes code + resources), or APK (Android app).

I'm not sure if **MyAppFree** and **MyApp** are separate Eclipse projects; if they are, under Android Studio and Gradle I'd encourage you to combine them into one module that has free and paid flavors. Build flavors are designed explicitly to aid this sort of use case. See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors for more info.

**UPDATE**

In the comments below it looks like you have a very large number of libraries. In that you probably don't want to build them all from source all the time, or manage a project that has dozens of modules. In that scenario, keeping modules that don't change very often as separate projects makes more sense. Those projects can compile to JAR or AAR, which brings us back to your original question of how to make those work in Android Studio.

You could copy JAR files into a `libs` directory under your project root and link them in. I believe there are problems trying to do the same with AAR libraries; see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63908 to track the progress of that. If you don't want to maintain multiple copies of the libraries, you could either try symlinking the directories (I *think* that will work), or you could set up a local Maven repository and have the side projects publish their artifacts to that. I don't have links with detailed instructions on that at my fingertips; you could start with http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html.

There will be a fair learning curve to getting a local Maven repo set up, but once it's done, you'll probably find that it solves your problem pretty cleanly, and if you're in a shop with multiple developers and would like an organization-wide Maven repo, perhaps with artifacts that are published to it from a build server, you can set that up.

Comment: Yes MyAppFree and MyApp are separate project and could be considered flavors. So from what i'm reading gradle is not suitable for my case. Because my libraries are shares across all my apps. And I can't have a copy of all libraries in all applications just because they need to be in the same root.

Comment: If you make one big project at the root that has all of the libraries and apps as modules, it will work well. I think it makes sense in your case. You just can't have separate projects with dependencies that are outside the project root.

Comment: I have a total of 45 project between libraries and apps. What you are saying is that I create a big project to load all of them??? did you considered the amount of memory that I need to have for Android-studio just to have all the projects open at the same time?

Comment: Hmm, 45 projects sounds super-complicated. In that sort of scenario you're unlikely to want to build all those dependencies from source all the time, but will instead probably want to compile some of them to jar or aar files that you include. A frustrating limitation you'll hit is that we can't pull in source directories for jar libraries yet through Gradle, which will hurt you there. As for memory, Android Studio is memory-hungry, but that's not an easy problem to solve. I don't mean to be flippant, but memory is cheap -- 16 GB is less than 150 USD. Your productivity is much more valuable.

Comment: My problem is described by another user in this page: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62177. I hope they add support soon. I will try intelliJ projects instead of gradle for now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe go to the menu "Project Structure" (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S) and add the desired dependencies to the correct modules.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Your Project Structure should be looking like this

```
YourProjectName

-libraries
 --myLib1
 --myLib2
 --myLib3

-MyAppBase
 --build.gradle( It will have dependency of all three libraries like mentioned in last)
 --src
 --res

-MyApp

 --src
   ---main
      ----java
      ----res
      ----Manifest
   ---full
      ----java
      ----res
      ----Manifest
   ---free
      ----java
      ----res
      ----Manifest


 --build.gradle ( It will have dependency of only MyAppBase because your MyAppBase is already having dependency of all of your three libraries so no need to include them again)
```

Now you can have your build flavors in this last mentioned build.gradle file like

```
 buildTypes {

     debug {
         runProguard false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

     }

     release{
         runProguard false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
         signingConfig signingConfigs.prodSigning // write your signingConfig

      }
   }

 productFlavors{

     full {
         //required configuration for full version

     }

     free {
          //required configuration for full version

     }

 }
```

**Note** your directory name and product falvours name in build.gradle file must be same so while compilation (from Built Variant tab available in Left panel or command prompt) it will automatically take the code/res/manifest from respective folder.

Above configuration will give four type of following build variants

```
debugFull,debugFree,releaseFull,releaseFree
```

You Can add dependency in build.gradle of MyAppBase like

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:myLib1')
    compile project(':libraries:myLib2')
    compile project(':libraries:myLib3')
}
```

And in the MyApp module's build.gradle file like this

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':MyAppBase')      
}
```

Comment: I've replied to Scott Barta I can't have a single project with all my 45 libraries + apps. What I want Is just open an app project with it's dependecies

Comment: @pyus13, you should use flavors for things like full/free, not build types.

Comment: @ScottBarta thanks for correcting me, I was thinking about the flavors but written buildtypes.