# Android Studio (gradle) generates double size apk file for paid version

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I build my paid version, Android Studio (and Gradle) generates a double size apk file?

It's the same result generating apk from Android Studio and/or command line:

```
gradle clean assembleRelease
```

It includes the following directories extra:

```
assets/
main/
paid/
```

thus making it very large.

My build.gradle has the following definition for the paid version:

```
sourceSets {

    paid {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/paid']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

}
```

In my src/paid/res directory I only have the following extra (unzip from apk):

```
40  ./res/drawable
8   ./res/drawable-hdpi
8   ./res/drawable-ldpi
8   ./res/drawable-mdpi
8   ./res/raw
8   ./res/raw-de
8   ./res/raw-sv
16  ./res/values
8   ./res/values-de
8   ./res/values-sv
120 ./res
120 .
```

And I use the following:

```
productFlavors {

    free {
        packageName "com.xyz.abc"
    }

    paid {
        packageName "com.xyz.abcpro"
    }

}
```

Directory sizes below (unzip from apk):

Free:

```
208 ./META-INF
8   ./org/apache/http/client
8   ./org/apache/http/entity/mime
8   ./org/apache/http/entity
24  ./org/apache/http
24  ./org/apache
24  ./org
888 ./res/drawable
584 ./res/drawable-hdpi
552 ./res/drawable-ldpi
560 ./res/drawable-mdpi
16  ./res/drawable-xhdpi
16  ./res/drawable-xxhdpi
488 ./res/layout
32  ./res/layout-land
8   ./res/layout-v10
16  ./res/layout-v17
8   ./res/layout-v7
8   ./res/layout-v8
64  ./res/menu
16  ./res/raw
16  ./res/raw-de
16  ./res/raw-sv
80  ./res/xml
3368    ./res
8448    .
```

Paid:

```
8   ./assets/scripts
8   ./assets
1000    ./main/res/drawable
720 ./main/res/drawable-hdpi
584 ./main/res/drawable-ldpi
656 ./main/res/drawable-mdpi
16  ./main/res/drawable-xhdpi
24  ./main/res/drawable-xxhdpi
504 ./main/res/layout
40  ./main/res/layout-land
8   ./main/res/layout-v10
16  ./main/res/layout-v17 
8   ./main/res/layout-v7
8   ./main/res/layout-v8
64  ./main/res/menu
16  ./main/res/raw
16  ./main/res/raw-de
16  ./main/res/raw-sv
152 ./main/res/values
72  ./main/res/values-de
72  ./main/res/values-sv
96  ./main/res/xml
4088    ./main/res
4104    ./main
368 ./META-INF
8   ./org/apache/http/client
8   ./org/apache/http/entity/mime
8   ./org/apache/http/entity
24  ./org/apache/http
24  ./org/apache
24  ./org
40  ./paid/res/drawable
8   ./paid/res/drawable-hdpi
8   ./paid/res/drawable-ldpi
8   ./paid/res/drawable-mdpi
8   ./paid/res/raw
8   ./paid/res/raw-de
8   ./paid/res/raw-sv
16  ./paid/res/values
8   ./paid/res/values-de
8   ./paid/res/values-sv
120 ./paid/res
120 ./paid
888 ./res/drawable
584 ./res/drawable-hdpi
552 ./res/drawable-ldpi
560 ./res/drawable-mdpi
16  ./res/drawable-xhdpi
16  ./res/drawable-xxhdpi
488 ./res/layout
32  ./res/layout-land
8   ./res/layout-v10
16  ./res/layout-v17
8   ./res/layout-v7
8   ./res/layout-v8
64  ./res/menu
16  ./res/raw
16  ./res/raw-de
16  ./res/raw-sv
80  ./res/xml
3368    ./res
14656   .
```

Free apk size:

-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff  952930 Jan  6 10:01 free-release.apk

Paid apk size:

-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff  1880495 Jan  6 10:00 paid-release.apk

It's a standard Android Studio setup with main/
and then parallell to main/ the following directory paid/:

```
.
./res
./res/drawable
./res/drawable/ic_launcher.png
./res/drawable/widget_icon_large.png
./res/drawable/widget_icon_small.png
./res/drawable-hdpi
./res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
./res/drawable-ldpi
./res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png
./res/drawable-mdpi
./res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
./res/raw
./res/raw/help.html
./res/raw-de
./res/raw-de/help.html
./res/raw-sv
./res/raw-sv/help.html
./res/values
./res/values/commons.xml
./res/values/strings.xml
./res/values-de
./res/values-de/strings.xml
./res/values-sv
./res/values-sv/strings.xml
```

Studio layout:
[image]

Update1:

When I added an empty directory free parallell to paid and changed the following:

```
sourceSets {

    free {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/free']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    paid {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/paid']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

}
```

Now *both* apk has the same and double size!?

Update2:

Removed sourceSets all together and it worked!

Comment: Interesting, do you have exclusive resources (like app logo) in both directories?

Comment: strings.xml I have in both directories but in paid only the specific changes for paid. In raw, same filename in both directories but with different content all together. In drawable I have the same file name for the launcher icon, but with different color design. Other than that all is in default place with no duplication for paid.

Comment: You've listed the directory sizes, but what's actually in the directories that doesn't belong that accounts for the size difference?

Comment: I am not sure if the your directory named paid as one of your paid flavor directory and productFlavor name also paid created any problem.

Comment: @pyus13 Could you explain a bit more...

Comment: @powder366 actually what happens in Gradle if you configure any flavor while compilation the build automatically takes contain of the directory with the same name, like in your case paid is the flavor and paid is the directory name as well.You include it in sourceSets as well so I doubt if it is including them twice. Have you tried keeping the different name of directory. Check the Note written in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890205/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio-gradle/20892146#20892146

Comment: @pyus13 I tried to rename the directory from paid to pro. Also then changed sourceset to java.srcDirs = ['src/pro']. Did not help. Also generally changed res.srcDirs = ['src/paid/res'] to res.srcDirs = ['src'] Also please check my Update1 for another test I did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are specifying sourceSets incorrectly.

If you go back to the original configuration, product flavors free and paid, resources in src/paid/res, you can remove the sourceSets elements and the app should build fine.

Comment: I removed sourceSets all together in build.gradle and kept the structure src/main/* and src/paid/res (still not sure technically why my sourceSets messed it up)